# a:hover is making the next link inline disappear and double images it over the link the mouse is on

Tags: css, hover, z-index

[image]I am trying to do a simple html/css hover design test. I have five links in a list, they are inline. I wanted the effect of  a column that stretched for the length of the page when the mouse rolled over the link. So for example, if my mouse is over the first link 1399 the text for 1499 appears like a double image over the 1399 link. Or for example in the image below the 1699 is not showing.
That worked but, mostly. (I wish there was a way to make the hover column go behind the other elements in the body of the document, i don't think it is possible to give z attributes to hover )...I noticed that it makes the text from the next link disappear from the order it is in and double images over the link the mouse is covering.

this is the html

```
<div id = box1>
<ul id=list1>
<li><a href>1399 </a></li>
<li><a href>1499 </a></li>
<li><a href>1599 </a></li>
<li><a href>1699 </a></li>
<li><a href>1799 </a></li>
<li><a href>1899 </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

this is the css

```
a:link {
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
}

a:hover
{
color:#fff;
position:absolute;
background-color:blue;
opacity:0.5;
min-height:100%;
max-width: 70px;
//z-index: 1;
//top:0;
//left:0;
//right:0;
//bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: hm... `//` is not the syntax for commenting out a line in CSS.  You need `/* commented */` instead.

Comment: the "was" to test out possible elements. It removes the line as a command and leaves it as comment. As I understand you can use // or /* depending on your preference.

Comment: `//` is not correct.  Placing `//` in front of a rule just makes it an unknown property and is thus ignored.  `##` would have the same effect.

Comment: Joseph I appreciate it, but it seems to work just fine. It is also not related to the question.

Comment: hm... z-index should work, but when I try to replicate the code, there's not enough there to build a working example.  Do you have a demo up or could you post more code?

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that your `position: absolute` is taking the `<a>` out of the flow (that is why the 1799 moves over to where it was), and the 1699 itself is being pushed off screen because your `min-height: 100%` is causing it to make the `<a>` 100% of the screen height, yet the `<a>` starts below the top of the screen height. I think you can achieve the effect you want by replacing your `hover` code with this:

```
a:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
a:hover:after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:blue;
    opacity:0.5;
    max-width: 70px;
    z-index: -1;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

The only thing is, I'm not able to test this right now to see if the `after` pseudoelement can be combined with the `hover` pseudo class. If not, then I recommend using the same idea by creating a `<div>` inside the `<a>` tag to become the column effect.

EDIT (based off the code you offered)

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu_wrapper">
<div id="menu">

<ul   
<li><a href>1399</a></li>   
<li><a href>1499</a></li>   
<li><a href>1599</a></li>   
<li><a href>1699</a></li>   
<li><a href>1799</a></li>    
<li><a href>1899</a></li>   
<li><a href>1999</a></li>  
<li><a href>2999</a></li>   
</ul>

</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p>Ullamco laboris nisi ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Quis nostrud exercitation
  duis aute irure dolor lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad
  minim veniam. Ullamco laboris nisi eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
  occaecat quis nostrud exercitation mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Consectetur adipisicing elit,
  sunt in culpa in reprehenderit in voluptate. Ullamco laboris nisi sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt qui officia deserunt. Duis aute irure dolor cupidatat non
  proident, velit esse cillum dolore. Ut enim ad minim veniam, lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, excepteur sint occaecat.</p>

<img src="../images/myimage.png" alt="" />
</div>

</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body {height: 100%; background-color: #F0F095; }
#menu_wrapper {width:900px; margin: 0 auto; height:150px;
background-color:#CC3300;border: 4px solid #000;}
#menu{margin:15px;border: 4px solid #000; height:25px;}
#menu ul{}
#menu ul, #menu li {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; text-indent:0;}
#menu ul li{ width:70px; float:left; }
#menu ul li:hover:after {content: ''; position:absolute;min-height:100%;width:70px; background-color:yellow; z-index:0; margin-left: -70px; opacity: .5}

a{width:100%; line-height: 25px; position: relative; z-index: 1;
text-align:center; float: left;
}
#wrapper {min-height:100%; background-color:#F1CA49; width: 1000px; margin: 25px auto;}
```

Comment: Scott thank you! will try it out. I went to http://www.w3schools.com looking up the content tag. I thought the absolute was doing it but could not figure out how. Thank you for explaining it. will work on it an see how it goes.

Comment: It's the `content` property of the `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements.

Comment: Scott thank you I am still trying to get the code to work using the content: ''; got some interesting results but not quite working yet.

Comment: It seemed to work for me when I deleted the `max-width` and added `width: 2em` (for your 4-digit numbers; for a test I also added an `li {float: left;}`). What kind of problem are you having?

Comment: your content might work better, but am still looking at css info/www3 to see how to implement it. Just never used the content before.

Comment: I've updated based off what you gave. Not sure it is quite what you want, but should be closer. PS Next time, add your code by editing your question (if you can) instead of posting as answers.

Comment: Will do thank you. Still new to the stackoverflow system and I thought if I found something that might work I should put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again Scott. In case this helps any one else am adding this CSS code. Received  from Dsonesuk on the http://w3schools forum and it seems to work great and is almost 100% close to what I was trying to accomplish.

```
html, body {height:100%; background-color: #F0F095; }
#menu_wrapper {width:900px; margin: 0 auto; height:150px; 
background-color:#CC3300;border: 4px solid #000;}
#menu{margin:15px;border: 4px solid #000; height:25px;}
#menu ul{width:960px; position:absolute; height:100%;}
#menu ul, #menu li {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; text-indent:0;}
#menu ul li{ width:70px; float:left;minheight:100%;position:relative; }
#menu ul ul {position:absolute;min-height:100%;width:70px; left: -32em; 
background  color:#FFFF00; z-index:0;}
#menu ul li:hover ul {left:0; top:25px;}
#menu ul li:hover{background-color:yellow;}
#content {position:relative; z-index:999;}
a{width:100%; line-height: 25px; /*vertical align text SHOULD MATCH HEIGHT VALUE*/
float:left; /* use to stace side by side OR comment out to stack above eace other*/
text-align:center; /*use for fixed width */
}
#wrapper {min-height:100%; background-color:#F1CA49; width: 1000px; margin: 25px auto;}
```

Comment: This is not very useful without the html.

Answer (score -1):

ok. sorry, will try this again, 
here is the html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<link rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" href="try1.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu_wrapper">
<div id="menu">

<ul>

<li><a href="#">1399</a><ul><li></li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">1499</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">1599</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">1699</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">1799</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">1899</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">1999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">2999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">3999</a><ul><li></li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">4999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">5999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">6999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

</ul>

</div>
</br>

<div id="menu">

<ul>

<li><a href="#">7999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">8999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">9999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

<li><a href="#">0999</a><ul><li> </li> </ul></li>

</ul>

</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p>Ullamco laboris nisi ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Quis nostrud exercitation
  duis aute irure dolor lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad
  minim veniam. Ullamco laboris nisi eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
  occaecat quis nostrud exercitation mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Consectetur adipisicing elit,
  sunt in culpa in reprehenderit in voluptate. Ullamco laboris nisi sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt qui officia deserunt. Duis aute irure dolor cupidatat non
  proident, velit esse cillum dolore. Ut enim ad minim veniam, lorem ipsum dolor
  sit amet, excepteur sint occaecat.</p>

<img src="../images/myimage.png" alt="" />
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```